# Presenting a view controller that doesn't have a nib file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

How would I go about presenting a view controller that doesn't have a nib file?

I have a viewController without a nib and would like to have this view displayed when a user touches a button. Is it necessary to also have a nib file to do this?

thanks for any help.

I ended up using:

```
CameraViewController *cvc = [[CameraViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:YES];
        [cvc release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the view programmatically instead of inside of the nib. Then a nib would not be needed.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
CameraViewController *cameraViewController = [[CameraViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:cameraViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I have the views programmatically. how would I then link to that view from another viewcontroller? thanks

Comment: You could expose them as properties.

Comment: If my viewController is called CameraViewController, what would I put in the following method to load that ViewController if I don't have a nib file?

- (IBAction)showCamera:(id)sender { }

Comment: You create the view controller like any other objective-C object: [[CameraViewController alloc] init];  How you then show it depends on whether you're using a single view controller, a UINavigationViewController, a UITabViewController to display your previous one.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a nib for a view controller.  In general, it can be useful to have a nib because of maintenance and other things; but if you don't want a nib you'll want to override the `-loadView` method provided by `UIViewController`.